# rails 4 with link_to and method post with strong parameters

Tags: http-post, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to, strong-parameters

I'm stuck in a problem which can't be that complicated, but I'm just not getting things right.

Assuming I've got two Models:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device

  validates :number, presence: true
end
```

and

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :notifications, :dependent => :destroy

  //rest omitted for brevity
end
```

with nested routes like so:

```
 resources :devices do
   resources :notifications
 end
```

and a notifications controller like so:

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_device, :only => [:index, :new, :create]
  before_filter :load_notification, only: :create

  load_and_authorize_resource :device
  load_and_authorize_resource :notification, :through => :device


  def index
  end

  def new
    @notification = @device.notifications.build
  end

  def create
    params.each do |param|
      logger.debug param
    end
    @notification = @device.notifications.build(notification_params)
    if @notification.save
      redirect_to [@notification.device, @notifications], notice: 'Notification was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def load_notification
    @notification = Notification.new(notification_params)
  end

  def set_device
    @device = Device.find(params[:device_id])
  end

  def notification_params
    params.fetch(:notification, {}).permit(:number, :device_id, :message)
  end
end
```

Now when it comes to create notifications:
The Form works as aspected. BUT: I want to achieve a second goal.
Notifications should be resendable, so I have this in notifications index view:

```
<%= link_to 'Resend', device_notifications_path(number: notification.number, message: notification.message), :method => :post %>
```

But the validation fails and im redirected to new page without any prefilled fields telling me that number is required, so there must be missing something obvious I don't get.

The params from the request:

```
[["user_id", xyz]]
["_method", "post"]
["authenticity_token", "myauthenticitytokenstring"]
["number", "+1555123456789"]
["action", "create"]
["controller", "notifications"]
["device_id", "9"]
["notification", {}]
```

(Message is not required)

I think the error lies in my notification_params method in the controller.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem just now, and this is what worked for me:

```
<%= link_to 'Resend', device_notifications_path(@notification.device_id, notification: { number: notification.number, message: notification.message }), :method => :post %>
```

Basically, you need to wrap your controller/model data into a hash for the controller's params. That's just how the controller itself reads it. Also, are you not missing the `device_id` in your `device_notifications_path` ?

```
[["user_id", xyz]]
["_method", "post"]
["authenticity_token", "myauthenticitytokenstring"]    
["action", "create"]
["controller", "notifications"]
["device_id", "9"]
["notification", {["number", "+1555123456789"]}]
```

Now, in saying that, I'm just assuming that `device_id` is located in your URL route:
    `http:\\localhost:3000\notifications\9`

This is why `device_id` would not have to be in the hash itself. This is just based on what I'm assuming here without more of the `view` and `routes` to go on. All in all, it does have to do with the hash. Play around a bit, and use `p` to print out data in your development.log to test:

```
def create
  p params
  p notification_params

  ...
end
```

In addition, optional but not required, you could DRY up your controller's params def using `.require` instead of `.fetch` like this:

```
private

def notification_params
  params.require(:notification).permit(:number, :device_id, :message)
end
```