# Unsatisfiable strong params when using button_to for an update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm having trouble understanding how to satisfy strong params when using `button_to` to do an `update` action. I'm trying to set an attribute called `active` to the value of `true` for an existing instance of a class called `Plan`.

*(Note that I'm using HAML for my views here.)*

This works:

```
= form_for(plan, remote: true) do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :active, value: true
  = f.submit 'set active'
```

But this doesn't:

```
= button_to "set active", plan_path(plan, active: true), method: :put, remote: true
```

**Error**

> Completed 400 Bad Request in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
>
> ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is
>   empty: plan:
>     actionpack (4.2.1)  lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:249:in 'require'
>     () Users/Rob/Sites/drexel_msis_planner/app/controllers/plans_controller.rb:77:in 'plan_params'
>     () Users/Rob/Sites/drexel_msis_planner/app/controllers/plans_controller.rb:45:in 'block in update'
>    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:210:in 'respond_to'
>    () Users/Rob/Sites/drexel_msis_planner/app/controllers/plans_controller.rb:44:in 'update'

**Routes**

```
          user_plans GET    /users/:user_id/plans(.:format)               plans#index
                     POST   /users/:user_id/plans(.:format)               plans#create
       new_user_plan GET    /users/:user_id/plans/new(.:format)           plans#new
           edit_plan GET    /plans/:id/edit(.:format)                     plans#edit
                plan PATCH  /plans/:id(.:format)                          plans#update
                     PUT    /plans/:id(.:format)                          plans#update
                     DELETE /plans/:id(.:format)                          plans#destroy
```

**Controller**

```
# PATCH/PUT /plans/1
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @plan.update(plan_params)
      format.js { flash.now[:notice] = "Plan was successfully updated." }
    end
  end
end

private 

def plan_params
  params.require(:plan).permit(:user_id, :name, :active)
end
```

---

It seems like such a silly issue but I can't figure it out and [the API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) doesn't seem to give any clues as to why it wouldn't be working.

These are but a few of the variations that I've tried (each is followed by its accompanying error message):

```
= button_to "set active", plan_path(plan: plan, active: true), method: :put, remote: true
```

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches
>   {:action=>"update", :active=>true, :controller=>"plans", :plan=>#,
>   :user_id=>"104"} missing required keys: [:id]:

```
= button_to "set active", plan_path(id: plan.id, active: true), method: :put, remote: true
```

> Completed 400 Bad Request in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
>
> ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is
>   empty: plan:   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:249:in `require'

```
= button_to "set active", plan, active: true, method: :put, remote: true
```

> ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is
>   empty: plan:   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:249:in 'require'
>   ()
>   Users/Rob/Sites/drexel_msis_planner/app/controllers/plans_controller.rb:77:in
>   'plan_params'    ()
>   Users/Rob/Sites/drexel_msis_planner/app/controllers/plans_controller.rb:45:in
>   'block in update'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to finally resolve this based on the information in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248304/rails-4-with-link-to-and-method-post-with-strong-parameters).

Instead of placing the parameters in their own hash as another argument to `button_to`, I included them inside of the call to the `plan_path` method. The first argument needs to be the model's ID, and the second argument needs to be the model's name as a key with a hash of the desired attributes as its value. (Example below):

```
= button_to "set active", plan_path(plan.id, plan: { active: true }), method: :put, remote: true
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the submitted params the difference is that your form results in `params` being

```
{ "id" => 123, "plan" => {"active" => true}, "controller" => "...", "action" => "..."}
```

Whereas the second results in

```
{ "id" => 123, "active" => true, "controller" => "...", "action" => "..."}
```

And in that case `params[:plan]` is nil, which leads to the error you see.

There are multiple ways to fix this. You could change the submitted parameters to match what the controller currently expects, for example

```
button_to set_active, plan, method: :put, remote: true, params: {"plan[active]" => 1}
```

(You could also have the parameters be part of the form URL as you were attempting but having as form fields feels slightly more correct to me).

Alternatively, if this update action isn't used by any other forms, then change it to match the submitted data. I wouldn't normally do this - it would be very easy but your app will be easier to think about if things behave in predictable ways.

Comment: Doing it that way still gave me:

NoMethodError - undefined method `permit' for "active=true":String:

Comment: Ah, button_to not as smart as I recalled - you have to flatten the params hash for it

Comment: I appreciate the help as your approach of looking at the difference between the parameters being sent from the working form versus the button_to was what helped me figure it out. I wonder if the guide or API should be updated to make it easier for others as this was not intuitive. However, the process is somewhat intimidating so hopefully others will find this here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to, `params` should be a separate hash

`= button_to "set active", plan, method: :put, remote: true, params: { :active => true }`

Comment: I'm getting this error when writing it that way:

> Started PUT "/plans/103" for ::1 at 2015-05-24 01:42:53 -0400
> Processing by PlansController#update as JS
>   Parameters: 
>  "authenticity_token"=>"P8GHlfiBJZbpEsfHcVvTx3MvxnM5LT20ExVwu6+fgPY6nQthfFtW8QEK5pzPitTBRrGdLl9hrYrucTPpdjRdHA==", "active"=>"true", "id"=>"103"}
 ....

> Completed 400 Bad Request in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)

> ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: plan:
>   actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:249:in 'require'